# How to use preg_replace to hide parts of title

Tags: php, wordpress

I tried explaining this but I don't think anyone understood,

I have a lot of titles which are all different, what I'm trying to do, is get rid of every `"Lyrics"` word in the title, and also, everything that appears before the `"-"` symbol.

I managed to do the lyrics part with istr_replace

```
<?php echo str_ireplace('lyrics', '', get_the_title()); ?>
```

How can I do the second part, what can I apply  to the code to make it so?

Example of what I want it to do:

> "random title - more random title lyrics" turns to "more random title"

The code applied, would delete the `"random title - "` on every single title on my website,

I was previously given this by someone here, Idk if this would help

```
$string = preg_replace("/[^-]+-(.*) Lyrics/", "$1", $string);
```

Comment: what about just [ -]+(lyrics)

Comment: so using [ -]+(lyrics) would for example
Take out every word behind the "-" ?

Comment: No I tested this using the JavaScript regex tester and it seems to just grab the space and - before lyrics

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do it all in one regexp, that's probably asking too much. Why not break it up into two steps: remove everything up through - (and following spaces)

```
$string = preg_replace('/^[^-]*-\s*/, '', $string);
```

and then remove the first "lyrics" (case insensitive), if any

```
$string = preg_replace('/lyrics/i', '', $string);
```

This can get more complicated -- what if there are no or multiple hyphens, what if there are no or multiple "lyrics", what do you want to do about spaces or punctuation after the hyphen and around "lyrics", can "lyrics" be part of another word, what about arbitrary capitalization of "lyrics", etc.? You need to make sure it works as expected in all these cases.

Comment: Every single title is exactly the same format, no extra hyphens,

hello bob - bob hello lyrics